# Taking multiple types in a property setter

Tags: c#, types, properties, setter

I want to option to set a property with multiple types and am struggling to find a solution.

```
public static PropertyType Property
        {
            get { return Property;}
            set {
                if (value.GetType() == typeof(PropertyType))
                {
                    Property = value;                       
                }

                //Or any other type
                if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    Property = FunctionThatReturnsPropertyType(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope that makes sense, I am only ever setting the Property as one type but I would like to be able to assign to it with other types and then transform them within the setter - is this possible?

Comment: A series of overloaded `SetProperty()` methods would be much cleaner

Comment: @AlexK. Hi! I nearly went down that route but instead decided to make a number of generic transformation methods and call them before assigning to the property - I might even use them later since they are generic. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want looks like design error. 
In C# property's setter and getter have always the same type. So you have basically next choices:

- Make your property type `object` (or `dynamic` if you want to get even worse design) and transform values within the setter as you stated in the question - *i strongly recommend to avoid this approach*.
- Get away from `property` concept and create separate methods to get value of the field and assign from different types. *This approach will allow you to assign value if you dont know the type at compile-time while getter-method will be typed still correctly. But generally it still looks like bad design.*
- Make all the transformations outside the property, *This solution is preferred. You should know which type you will use in every separate case*.

Comment: Hi! I came to my own conclusion that it was indeed a design error, I ended up just calling the transformation method before the property was even involved. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Try Property type as object.

```
public static Object PropertyName
{
    get { return PropertyName; }
    set { PropertyName = value; }
}
```

Comment: And lose all type-safety.